# Connect to an already remembered SSID in iOS through Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, wifi, nehotspothelper

I am implementing an app through Xamarin.

Is it possible to programmatically connect to an SSID which is already remembered by the phone in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to connect to a known network, without providing the necessary credentials, due to various security reasons.

In order to connect to a network, you need to create a [NEHotspotConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfiguration)

The class requires either only SSID (for open networks), or SSID with some credentials for authentication.

After the configuration is created, you can connect via [NEHotspotConfigurationManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager) like so:

```cs
await NEHotspotConfigurationManager.SharedManager.ApplyConfigurationAsync(config);
```

NB: Keep in mind that to connect to a network, you need to enable the `Hotspot` capability in your App Capabilities [Working with capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/capabilities/).

Comment: Thank you for your detail answer!